# Flutter Error: this ad may have not beens loaded or has been disposed. Ad with the following id could not be found

Tags: flutter

I'm on a Flutter project implementing a social post list where people will post everyday comments. And that list will have ads. Since my project is an MPV, I am using the [native_ads_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/native_ads_flutter) feature with multiple ads using the same ID. When I was loading the list of posts at once, it wasn't throwing any errors, but after I implemented pagination on this list, the ads are presented with a red screen with the message

> this ad may not have loaded or has been discarded. Unable to find the
> ad with the following ID 1

I asked ChatGPT for help and he gave me this answer.

> Based on your most recent explanation, it appears that you are using
> the same ID for multiple repeating ads in your listing.
>
> In this context, it is possible that the error you are facing in the
> NativeAd feature of your Flutter project, mainly when using
> pagination, is related to this use of repeated IDs.
>
> Ad providers often expect unique IDs for each ad as this helps in
> tracking, managing and correctly displaying ads. When repeating the
> same ID for multiple ads, there may be problems loading and displaying
> the ads correctly, resulting in errors like the one you mentioned.
>
> Therefore, it is important to ensure that each listing ad has a unique
> ID, even if the ad content is the same. Each ad instance must have its
> own unique ID associated with it.
>
> I recommend reviewing your code to ensure that you are assigning
> unique IDs to each ad in the list, even if the ad content is repeated.
> This should help you avoid conflicts and errors when loading and
> displaying your ads, especially when paging.
>
> If you're using a specific ad provider, check that provider's
> documentation for more guidance on the correct use of ad IDs and how
> to handle pagination in conjunction with repeating ads.

So it could be the problem with the error message `this ad may not have loaded or has been dismissed. Could not find the ad with the following id 1` is it linked to what ChatGPT explained?

This is the error message

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2):

In order to control ad loading and display, I utilize a flag variable and check if the adFlag boolean variable is true. However, I noticed an issue when the page is closed using Navigator.pop. To resolve this issue, I set the boolean variable to false in the dispose method.

Comment: Wao thanks, i didn't know this your such a life saver